# Use last value from a specific Cell

Tags: google-sheets

I've looked everywhere for a solution with no joy and with no experience with Spreadsheet functions to figure this out myself, I've turned to asking it here.

Basically i need to display the previous value of a cell in another: I.E.
If cell B3 changes from 50 to 60, i need cell G3 to show 50.

I've tried:

```
=INDEX(B3:B; COUNT(B3:B))
```

with no joy.

Answer (score 0):

we cant save data permanent when you delete your data in your sheet it wont save another place or it won't display anywhere